# Ubuntu Terminal (Windows App) Traceroute protocol not supported

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, network-protocols, traceroute

I'm using the Ubuntu Terminal from the windows store in order to do some tests with traceroute. 
The problem is, whenever I do that, I just get lines of starts like:

`traceroute www.google.com
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
(etc)...`

I've tried to fix this with -T and then I got:
[image]

Does anyone know a fix?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install inetutils-traceroute
sudo apt install traceroute
```

turn off windows firewall

and try

```
inetutils-traceroute -M icmp www.google.com
```

https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/1930

Comment: It's still giving me * * * unfortunately. I'll keep looking for solutions. I'll post it here if I find it.

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution for your problem. Works like a charm !
Log on Ubuntu as root typing on terminal 'sudo --login' and your admin password on terminal. After this type traceroute -I (for me traceroute works well only using echo icmp type 8) host.
Or alternatively type 'sudo traceroute -I host' and after your password.
Sorry for my bad english.. :(
Enjoy !

Answer (score 0):

Following the [@Alex_Krug](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9041875/alex-krug) answer worked, but you need to use the long form which is not ideal. Would have expected "traceroute 192.168.1.1" to work.

```
inetutils-traceroute -M icmp 192.168.1.1
```